# POJO to XML mapping in Java to avoid breaking XHR

Tags: xml, mapping, xmlhttprequest

Let's say I have a simple POJO class:

```
public void Foo {
    public int a;
    public int b;

    public Foo() {
        a = 0;
        b = 1;
    }
}
```

Is there some library in JAVA which will give me XML like this:

```
<List>
    <a value='0'/>
    <b value='1'/>
</List>
```

I have a XHR service but I have to manually "dump" each member to XML to send it back to the client. It could avoid me some trouble if dumping was automated.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/); it should do what you need.  Out of the box, I would expect it to produce something like this from your `Foo` class:

```
<foo>
  <a>0</a>
  <b>1</b>
</foo>
```

However you can customize the representation of your class through annotations on your class.